# C# winforms, при попытке установить библиотеку Emgu.CV.runtime.windows студия выдает ошибку, приведенную ниже

Tags: c#, winforms

Ошибка      Не удалось установить пакет «Emgu.runtime.windows.msvc.rt.arm64 19.33.31630». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Comment: Вместо Windows Forms (Framework) создайте проект по другому шаблону - просто Windows Forms, и выберите .NET 6 или 7.